How to call a method only after a specified time has elapsed?
Using SignalR to send updates to the UI when a user performs actions can lead to frequent calls, which I want to limit. Instead of sending updates every time an action occurs, I would like to send updates only after a certain amount of time has passed since the last action.
    private async Task UserSessionUpdated(UserUpdateMessageUpdateCommand auto)
    {
        if (settings.interval is not null && settings.interval.Value > 0)
        {
            _stopwatch ??= new Stopwatch();
            if (_stopwatch.ElapsedMilliseconds > _appSettings.interval.Value ||
                _stopwatch.ElapsedMilliseconds == 0)
            {                   
                await HubContext.Clients.All.SendAsync("UserUpdateMessage", "load");
                _stopwatch.Reset();
                _stopwatch.Start();
                
            }
        }
        else
        {               
            await HubContext.Clients.All.SendAsync("UserUpdateMessage", "load");
        }
    }

    
    protected override async Task ExecuteAsync(CancellationToken stoppingToken)
    {
        await Bus.PubSub.SubscribeAsync<UserUpdateMessageUpdateCommand>("", UserSessionUpdated,
            cancellationToken: stoppingToken);
    }

While using a stopwatch is an option, it has the drawback of continuously ticking even if there are no actions for a day.
Is there a way to implement a throttling mechanism for this purpose? Can someone assist me with using throttling to achieve this?

Is having frequent SignalR calls a problem? If so, why?

We need to limit the calls since we don't want to update user ui for every call

Do you just want to drop those calls or accumulate into one call with N datapoints?

Within configured interval, only one time even if multiple actions happened

You send a message to all clients to matter who was the receiver?

Yes, to all users, but want to limit frequent refresh update to UI

Can I understand the requirement as: 1. no notification if there's no any user update, 2. send notification if there's user update, 3. the notification was not sent once user update occurred, it will be sent after the update occurred n seconds, 4. send the latest update if there're several updates with the n seconds. If so, I'm afraid we need to push the updates into a message queue to make sure all the updates will be records, and we need a mark to decide whether we need to send the notification.

If I didn't misunderstand, then the UserSessionUpdated should update the mark to be active and start a timeout, then read the last update in the queue and send to all clients.

Basically, you could take the timestamp of sending a message, add your desired dead-time and then discard all calls that happen before that resulting timestamp. That is assuming you have a relatively constant rate of incoming calls, maybe with some fluctuation but not "bursts" and then long periods of silence. To cover that or both you would have to adapt a little.

^^ It also assumes the instance of the class this is from would be a singleton or at least live for the entirety of the app lifetime. If that's not the case, you'd probably need a cache that's outside of that class.

This is basically BackgroundService in gateway and UserSessionUpdated will hit when user do action using rabbitmq

You could use Channels for that purpose - they offer having bounded queue of items to process. It is implementation of producer - consumer pattern - in our case we wount to bound the queue, so when it is full, it will be fully processed.
Here's simple implementation with explanations in code. You can use it as a template and put your methods in appropriate places:
// Sample DTO
public class SignalRMessageDto(DateTime dateTime)
{
    public DateTime DateTime { get; set; } = dateTime;
}

// Create bounded channel, with capacity of 10 items.
// Get the reader and the writer.
var channel = Channel.CreateBounded<SignalRMessageDto>(new BoundedChannelOptions(10));
var reader = channel.Reader;
var writer = channel.Writer;

await WriteMessages();

async Task WriteMessages()
{
    while (true)
    {
        var newMessage = new SignalRMessageDto(DateTime.Now);
        // Try write message - if channel will be at capacity
        // it won't accept new message and we will have
        // information to flush reader.
        var written = writer.TryWrite(newMessage);

        if (written == false)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Error when writing to channel");
            await FlushReader();
            // Now we should be able to write the message.
            _ = writer.TryWrite(newMessage);
        }
        else
            Console.WriteLine("Successfully written to channel");
        
        await Task.Delay(100);
    }
}

async Task FlushReader()
{
    Console.WriteLine("Flushing reader!");
    // We read and process all messages in channel.
    await foreach (var item in reader.ReadAllAsync())
    {
        Console.WriteLine(item.DateTime);
        // If we emptied channel, break.
        if (reader.Count == 0) break;
    }
}

UPDATE
To read messages in interval, change Channel.CreateBounded<SignalRMessageDto> to Channel.CreateUnbounded<SignalRMessageDto>, to hold arbitrary many messages and then define timer:
var timer = new Timer();
timer.Interval = 1000; // 1 second
timerElapsed += (o, e) => FlushReader();

Of course, you need to put some additional logic around it, to handle potential errors.

Within configured interval, send message to UI only one time even if multiple actions happened and also its a background service

@Anish please see update.
